# jmeter - Beanshell post processor

Tags: jmeter

Getting below error in log:

`2020-06-24 13:23:51,091 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: //to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 2020-06-24 13:23:51,091 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: //to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 2020-06-24 13:23:51,154 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: //to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 2020-06-24 13:23:51,154 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: //to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 2020-06-24 13:23:51,236 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: //to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 2020-06-24 13:23:51,236 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of://to output the execution flow in the jmeter.log to help demonstrate how the scr . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: sampler`

Below is the code used in Beanshell postprocessor.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

int tdNumber = ctx.getThreadNum();
int noThreads = ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads();
long tdstart = ctx.getThread().getStartTime();
long tdEnd = ctx.getThread().getEndTime();
String respCode = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
String respCode = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseMessage();
String samplerName = sampler.getName();


Date date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(date);

log.info("sampler::"+ sampleName +"....ThreadNo::"+ (tdNumber + 1) +" ....Starttime::"+ formattedDate +
"....StatusCode::" + respCode +"....TotalThreads::"+ noThreads +" ....Iterationno::"+vars.getIteration());
```

Answer (score 1):

> undefined variable or class name: sampler

There is no `sampler` shorthand in the Beanshell PostProcessor, you should use one of the following alternatives:

- `prev.getSampleLabel(false)`
- `ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName()`

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity.

More information on this `ctx`, `prev` and friends: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks  for the info ,one more query how to get start time of sample in groovy?

Comment: It is not related to the original question and you don't seem to be paying any attention to the provided documentation. As an exception here you go: `prev.getStartTime()`

Answer (score 0):

Move to [JSR223_PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) which is the best practice and include also `sampler`

> Migration to JSR223 PostProcessor+Groovy is highly recommended for performance, support of new Java features and limited maintenance of the BeanShell library.

Comment: what was the above issue could please help out.

Comment: @pavizham there's no sampler available in Beanshell PostProcessor, see in link